# SSRS - Date Format

Tags: reporting-services

We have just done an upgrade of SSRS from 2012 to 2016 and now something odd is happening, some not all of our reports are now showing dates in a US format when previously they were in a UK format (as we wanted). It's obviously a default but I can't seem to find where, the machine is set to UK time and location.

Does anyone know where this value is or what I should check?

Thanks,

Nic

Answer (score 0):

The date format in Preview mode in Report Designer is determined by the culture of the operating system, while the date format in the report manager depends on the culture of the browser.

have a look on below post

[SSRS - Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319086/ssrs-date-format)